# How to use several loops to make calculations in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 9 x 682 matrix (A). Every 36 columns correspond to a new variable (17 variable in total). For each variable (36 columns), I want to calculate the mean of every 6th column (i.e. mean of columns 1, 7, 13, 19, 31 and so on for each block of 36 columns.

I am stuck with the use of several For loops.

```
A_averaged = zeros(9,102);

for  i = 1:36:length(A)
    for j = i:i+35
        for k = j:6:j+1
            A_averaged(:,k) = mean(A(:,k), 2);
        end
    end
end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To vectorize this, I would reshape your data in a smart way, select the columns you want, and then compute the mean.

```
% Reshape data to 3D with dimensions: 9 x 36 x (nGroups)
B = reshape(A, size(A, 1), 36, []);

% Now grab the columns of each chunk you want
C = B(:, 1:6:end, :);

% Now compute the mean along the first dimension and squeeze the result
result = squeeze(mean(C, 1));
```

You can do this in one line with the following:

```
result = squeeze(mean(reshape(A(:, 1:6:end), size(A, 1), 6, []), 1))
```

If you instead want the mean of all rows and columns, you can reshape your data into `45 x nGroups` and compute the mean along the first dimension

```
result = mean(reshape(C, [], size(C, 3)), 1);
```

As a side note, your initial dimensions of `9 x 682` are not actually divisible by 36 columns. Did you mean `9 x 612`?

Comment: Indeed, I mean size(A) = 9 x 612.

Thanks for the useful answer.